# How to remove spaces while changing line in HTML?

Tags: html

There is a space between the first and second images.
How to remove the space while changing line in HTML?

```html
<div>
  <img src='http://lorempixel.com/100/100/abstract/1' />
  <img src='http://lorempixel.com/100/100/abstract/2' /><img src='http://lorempixel.com/100/100/abstract/3' />
</div>
```

Comment: Please clarify what you want to achieve. Do you want to keep a line break in your HTML code but to remove the white-space between the images? Or do you want the actual images to appear on separate lines?

Answer (score 0):

You have to modify the margin of your image :

```
img {
    margin-left: -4px;
}
```

Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

using css

```
<style>
    div img {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using css float property

```
img { 
  float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `float:left` to avoid the unwanted space or just place the html tags without space like `<img src="" /><img src="" /><img src="" />`
**Html**

```
<div class="divClass">
    <img src="">
    <img src="" /><img src="" />
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.divClass img{
    float:left;
}
```